# Azure: How to build *resilient* resource deployment pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

I am looking for some best practices and suggestions:

- My team is creating an Azure DevOps pipeline to deploy a complex infrastructure of VNets, VMs, Azure ML workspaces, SQL databases, etc.
- The pipeline uses Terraform where possible, but Powershell or AZ CLI where needed.
- The pipeline works, it is version controlled, it has proper unit tests and integration tests (or at least decent ones).

However, due to the instability of Azure resourcing **sometimes the pipeline will fail** because, for instance:

- SQL server provisioning fails
- AD join of VMs fails
- or other activities which are not due to bad Infra as Code, but rather the stochasticity of the task. Provisioning resources is inherently unstable, similar to networking, etc.

I am not complaining about Azure. I am just asking:

#### How can I adjust the IaC pipeline so that when Azure fails occur, some sort of retry can automatically be triggered?

As a concrete example, is there an Azure or Terraform equivalent to Python's [`tenacity`](https://tenacity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package or Java's [Spring Retry](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry)?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I adjust the IaC pipeline so that when Azure fails occur, some sort of retry can automatically be triggered?

You could try to use [Trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-trigger-pipeline&targetId=c519b80d-5d71-46b3-a8e0-3edf8c026ea2) task to trigger current build pipeline automatically when the build failed.

To be able to use the extension an Azure DevOps API endpoint needs to be created.
For the service connection to work as it should you need to configure the following parameters:

- Organization Url: The URL of the organization.
  ([https://dev.azure.com/[organization]](https://dev.azure.com/%5Borganization%5D))
- Personal Access Token: The personal access token.

Besides, we need to set the condition for this task, which will trigger the current pipeline **Only when a previous task has failed**:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Leo !  That's more involved than I was hoping, we don't currently have an API endpoint.  I will have to try it out with a toy pipeline and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: @MikeWilliamson, Sure, looking forward your reply.